# Finding overlapping dates for different IDs

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I wrote the following excel code to output true or false depending on, whether there are overlapping dates for a persons ID number. Please help me translate it into code for a new column in Power BI?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C4<=$D$2:$D$4392)*($D4>=$C$2:$C$4392)*($B4=$B$2:$B$4392))>1
```

*Column B is IDs, Column C is Start Date, and Column D is End Date -- see also [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VzT2.png)*

My logic is as follows.

There are three arrays in the formula:

- first is Boolean to see if the start date is before other end dates,
- second is Boolean to see if the end date is before other start dates, and
- third is to make sure it is the same ID number.

They are multiplied together into one array to find how many instances all the Boolean statements are true. SUMPRODUCT adds the values of that array together and if its greater than one, it is overlapping.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: added example to the original question

Answer (score 0):

This Calculated Column should work for you.

```
Overlap? =
VAR StartDate = 'Table'[Start]
VAR EndDate = 'Table'[End]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ID] ), 
        'Table'[Start] <= EndDate,
        'Table'[End] >= StartDate 
    ) > 1
```

The ALLEXCEPT function will filter the table to the rows that have the same ID as the current row (it actually removes all filters except the filter on the [ID] column).

The CALCULATE function counts the rows of the filtered table where [Start] is <= than the variable EndDate, which is the End value of the current row, and [End] is >= than the variable StartDate, which is the Start value of the current row. This is always true for the current row, but if the result is more than 1, then there are overlaps.

[image]

Comment: my data set was too big and i got an error "There's not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later when there may be more memory available." is there any way around this? data set is 130k+ lines